# Changing SAS date format

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a table with the dates in this forma

> 01FEB03| 00:00:00

What I want is to  make another table with a MMYY style format.

```
set merged_dpd_raw_2602;
formated_date=input(reporting_date,ddmmyy10.);

format formated_date MMYYs10.;


run;
```

This did not work.

````
data dpd_cnt_formated;
set dpd_cnt;

format reporting_date MMYYs10.;


run;```




EDIT:

data dpd_cnt_formated;
set dpd_cnt;

only_date=datepart(reporting_date) ;

format only_date MMYYs10.;


run;
````

Comment: What is the type and format on the original variable?

Comment: So either your date variable is character or you are using a user written format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you have going on, but this might help

```
data have;
  date_string = '01FEB03| 00:00:00';
run;

data want;
  set have;
  date = input(date_string, date9.);

  format date mmyys10.;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Probably want `DATE7.` for the informat since character number 8 is the `|`.

Comment: datepart(date) Was successful in removing the awkward date format in the original data.